# How to manually fail steps in Serenity bdd without skipping the other steps

Tags: java, linux, selenium, google-chrome, serenity-bdd

I use selenium and serenity to test a web app I've made and I wanna know if it's possible to manually make steps fail (with the red cross instead of the check icon)

But I want it to happen with the tests keep going and not skipping the other steps. Is it possible ?

Thanks a lot for you answer

Comment: so you mean to say you want to continue with your test even if the assertion is failed?

Comment: Yeah, I mean that for exemple, if I wanna check that all the pages from a menu are loading correctly. If one of them fails to load, I want the steps to be marked as failed, but keep going so the test continue to check if the other pages are correclty loading...